# ¿Como hacer rango de fechas en WindowsForms C#?

Tags: c#

a lo mejor para la mayoría es muy facíl, pero ya le llevo un tiempo batallando para que me quede y nomas no no puedo, en una aplicación que estoy haciendo quisiera hacer algo como lo de la imagen siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya he investigado en internet, pero solo consigo consultas sql, y según yo, para hacer esto no se necesita una consulta sql

Comment: Tu pregunta es como obtener el rango de fechas? como mostrarlo en pantalla? como ajustar los componentes para que se vean como en la imagen? como hacer que se muestren las fechas en ese formato?

Comment: como obtener ese rango de fechas

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes la fecha inicial(en este caso obteniendola actual):

```
DateTime fechaInicial = DateTime.Now;
DateTime fechaFinal;

fechaFinal = fechaInicial.AddDays(7); //Agrega 7 dias
fechaFinal = fechaInicial.AddWeeks(1); //Agrega una semana
```

En el siguiente link puedes ver la documentacion sobre como [agregar a una fecha](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.datetime.add?view=netframework-4.8)